# javascript data set property

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, dataset

i have set data in the html elements like

```
<button data-product={{ product.id }} data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-primary add-btn update-cart">Add to Cart</button>
```

and try to access them into the js file like:

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart');

   for(var i=0; i<updateBtns.length; i++){
      updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', ()=> {
      var action = this.dataset.action;
       var productId = this.dataset.product;
        })  
     }
```

but I got error that says cart.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'action' of undefined
at HTMLButtonElement.

Comment: `this` is pointing to the global (window) object and not your button. You either need to use a normal function or replace `this` with `updateBtns[i]`. [More info about this keyword here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use **this** word, you should not use the [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)!

```
for (var i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
  updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    var action = this.dataset.action;
    var productId = this.dataset.product;
  });
}
```

Comment: this one has worked but i didn't find any difference with my code. what going on sir.@cfarhad

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
for(var i=0; i<updateBtns.length; i++){
      updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', (event)=> {
      var action = event.target.dataset.action;
       var productId = event.target.dataset.product;
        })  
     }
```